# How to change a value name during output

Tags: sql

I am trying to change the name of a stored value when I execute my SQL script:

```
SELECT
    PERSONNUM, 
    PAYCODENAME, 
    CAST(WFCTIMEINSECONDS AS FLOAT)/3600 AS Total_Hours
FROM
    VP_ALLTOTALS
WHERE
    Applydate >= '09/25/2011' AND
    Applydate <= '10/01/2011' AND
    PAYCODENAME IN ('Vacation'
                    ,'Sick Leave - Paid'
                    ,'Personal Business - Paid'
                    ,'Comp Time - Paid'
                     )
```

I want the Vacation to be VAC, Sick Leave - Paid to be SIC, Personal Business - Paid to be PER and

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way is a list of `CASE` options for substitutions.

```
SELECT PERSONNUM
       PAYCODENAME CASE WHEN 'Vacation' THEN 'VAC'
                        WHEN 'Sick Leave - Paid' THEN 'SIC'
                        WHEN 'Personal Business - Paid' THEN 'PER'
                        ELSE PAYCODENAME END AS PAYCODENAME
       ....
```

Comment: `PAYCODENAME CASE` should be `CASE PAYCODENAME`, right?

Answer (score 3):

Use a [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement:

```
SELECT
    PERSONNUM, 
    CASE PAYCODENAME
    WHEN 'VACATION' THEN 'Vac'
    WHEN 'Sick Leave - Paid' THEN 'SIC'
    WHEN 'Comp Time - Paid' THEN 'PER'
    ELSE PAYCODENAME
    END,
    cast(WFCTIMEINSECONDS as float)/3600 as Total_Hours
FROM
    VP_ALLTOTALS
WHERE
    Applydate >= '09/25/2011' AND
    Applydate <= '10/01/2011' AND
    PAYCODENAME in ('Vacation'
    ,Sick Leave - Paid'
    ,'Personal Business - Paid'
    ,'Comp Time - Paid'
    )
```

Comment: -1 - Without an `ELSE` in your `CASE` then any values you don't explicitly handle become `NULL`

Comment: And now it's exactly like my answer but posted a minute and a half later :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a permanent table, derived table, or common table expression (subject to availability in your RDBMS) with the mappings and join onto that in place of the `in` list.

```
WITH PAYCODES(PAYCODENAME, LABEL)
     AS (SELECT 'Vacation',
                'VAC'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Sick Leave - Paid',
                'SIC'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Personal Business - Paid',
                'PER'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Comp Time - Paid',
                '')
SELECT PERSONNUM,
       LABEL AS PAYCODENAME,
       CAST(WFCTIMEINSECONDS AS FLOAT) / 3600 AS Total_Hours
FROM   VP_ALLTOTALS
       JOIN PAYCODES
         ON PAYCODES.PAYCODENAME = VP_ALLTOTALS.PAYCODENAME
WHERE  Applydate >= '09/25/2011'
       AND Applydate <= '10/01/2011'
```